# XML attributes order is changing after DOM processing using Java code

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to read an XML and writing into another XML by changing some attribute values When processing XML by means of standard DOM, attribute order is changing.
Here I am trying to change the 'id' attribute value of 'staff' element.

input xml:

```
<company  xyz="xyz" def="def">
   <staff id="1"  def="def"  xyz="xyz" abc="abc">
    <firstname>yong</firstname>
    <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
    <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
    <salary>100000</salary>
   </staff>
</company>
```

output xml:

```
<company  def="def" xyz="xyz">
    <staff abc="abc" def="def" id="2" xyz="xyz">
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

Expecting output xml:

```
<company  xyz="xyz" def="def">
   <staff id="2" def="def"  xyz="xyz" abc="abc">
    <firstname>yong</firstname>
    <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
    <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
    <salary>100000</salary>
   </staff>
</company>
```

Could someone please help with the source code.
Waiting for the responses.

Comment: why does this matter?

Comment: It will be arranged in alphabetic order.